Do I need to set contrasts in my model matrix when using the car package for type 3 ANOVA tables?
I have been running several general and generalized linear models (not linear regressions) using glmmTMB and lme4. After I receive my results from a model I run a type 3 ANOVA using car::Anova or glmmTMB::Anova.glmmTMB. Today, I was reading about Wald Chi-square and found a vignette that explains that contrasts must be specify in a model to correctly run an Anova. Based on these readings: Link 1, Link 2, and Link 3 (2 are copies of each other); it seems that contrasts need to be set for Type 3 Anova. However, it seems that setting contrasts seems only applicable to linear regression models and not general/ized linear models. Do I need to set contrasts for Type 3 Anova of general/ized linear models?
This is what my code usually looks like: glmmTMB:::Anova.glmmTMB(model, type = c("III"), test.statistic = c("Chisq"), component = "zi") or car::Anova(model, type = c("III"))
Thank you for your help!
